# AspectJ - Exclude try-finally block into aspect

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I have many methods like this:

```
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = new Connection();
        connection.connect();
        .... // method body

    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Can I exclude this part into apects (AspectJ)?

Comment: Yes you can, into an around-advice.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik ok, but I need to create `Connection` object and make it accessible to other code in method (i.e. in future i want to do like `connection.setMethod(...)`). It is possible?

Comment: It's certainly possible, the question is what you fancy. One idea is to use a `ThreadLocal`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik hmm.. can you explain more deeper your idea with `ThreadLocal`? You can write it as answer

Answer (score 2):

You can extract your connection management into an around-advice and make the contextual `Connection` available to the business code by exposing it in a `ThreadLocal`. Define a public class with a static property:

```
public class ConnectionHolder {
  public static final ThreadLocal<Connection> connection = new ThreadLocal<>();
}
```

In the around advice you must set the `ThreadLocal` to the open connection and **make very sure you unconditionally clear it afterwards**. This is the greatest pitfall with `ThreadLocal`s: leaking objects into unrelated contexts. Also beware of child thread inheriting the `ThreadLocal` (there was an issue with this in WebSphere once).

All in all, `ThreadLocal`s are quite a dirty solution, but anything else will require you to go for a dependency-injection framework like Spring, configure request-scoped beans, etc., which would be a good idea, but will take more research on your part.

Comment: Sorry for so lazy comment, but I want to make my code clear as possible, so I prefer to go with request scoped beans etc. Can you explain a little deeper how to achieve this using Spring? Actually I use Guice, so I try to port code to Guice if you provide me with Spring example/tips etc. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I remember, all you need is a `scope="request"` attribute on the bean declaration in the XML configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can extract the connection plumbing using the [template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) to avoid copy / paste. The basic idea is something like:

```
abstract ConnectionTemplate {
    private Connection connection = // ...

    /**
     * Method to be implementad by child classes
     */
    public abstract void businessLogicCallback(); 

    /**
     * Template method that ensure that mandatory plumbing is executed
     */
    public void doBusinessLogic() {
        try {
            openConnection();
            // fetch single result, iterate across resultset, etc
            businessLogicCallback();
        finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }

    void openConnection() {
        connection.open();
    }

    void closeConnection() {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, implementing classes can be as simple as

```
class ImportantBusinessClass extends ConnectionTemplate {

    @Override
    public void businessLogicCallback() {
        // do something important
    }
}
```

And you use it like

```
ImportantBusinessClass importantClass = new ImportantBusinessClass();
importantClass.doBusinessLogic();      // opens connection, execute callback and closes connection
```

---

Spring framework uses this technique in some places, notably the [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate) deals with SQL, connections, mapping between rows and domain objects, etc. Please refer to the [source code](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/3.2.x/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java) in GitHub for implementation details.

Comment: Thanks. But I need to control return type of the `businessLogicCallback`

Comment: The void method is just an example. If you look at the provided examples of JdbcTemplate, you will see that there are generic methods that return <T> based on a Class as an input argument. There are also methods that uses a [RowMapper<T>](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html) for returning a `List<T>` and [RowCallBackHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCallbackHandler.html) for state ful operations.